# Class member container iterators not compatible in member function std::find, but why not?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I hit some behaviour I can't seem to wrap my head around. Say I have a class defined as follows (a simple example for illustration):

```
class some_class
{
   public:
        some_class()
        {
            x_["0"] = "0";
            x_["1"] = "1";

            y_[0] = x_.find("0");
            y_[1] = x_.find("1");
        }

        int some_function(int i)
        {
            if(std::find(y_.begin(), y_.end(), x_.find("1")) != y_.end())
            {
                std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;

                return 1001;
            }

            return -1001;
        }

   private:
       std::unordered_map<string, string> x_;
       std::array<unordered_map<string, string>::iterator, 2> y_;
};
```

The code compiles with Visual Studio 2012 RC in *debug mode* (others modes not tested), but during call to **some_function** the program fails with a following assertion message

> ... microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\list Line: 289
>
> Expression: list iterators incompatible...

The calling code looks like this

```
auto vector<int> as;
as.push_back(1);   

auto vector<int> bs;   
auto some = some_class();

std::transform(as.begin(), as.end(), std::inserter(bs, bs.begin()), [=](int i) { return  some.some_function(i); });
```

#### Question:

What would be the problem with this kind of an arrangement? I get the code run fine if I declare **x_** and **y_** in **some_function** instead of as member variables. The class is being called/used in **std::transform** like occasions, if that should factored in to the situation.

<sup>As a tangential aside, it looks like the following declaration will be rejected by the compiler, should it be rejected?</sup>

```
std::unordered_map<string, string> x_;
std::array<decltype(x_.begin()), 2> y_;
```

The error message is

> error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Probably a problem with the copy constructor, that copies the iterators contained in the array and as such those iterators do not point to the map of the same object, but to the map of the object copied from.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates a `some_class` instance and calls `some_function`?

Comment: Please post a complete program that demonstrates the problem.  I've added `int main() { some_class().some_function(); }`; the program runs to completion.  Also, what do you think is wrong in your tangential aside?  The compiler accepts the declaration of `y_`.  (When asking questions, it is a good idea to verify that you have provided sufficient information to demonstrate the problem you are trying to solve.)

Comment: Try `const_iterator`. Also, you can use initializer lists: `x_{{"0","0"}, {"1","1"}}, y_{x_.find("0"), x_.find("1")}`

Comment: Consider your example... where is use of some?

Comment: @Charles: I edited the question to add the calling code (it looks like I had forgot the parameter from the original code, oh well). There's a huge difference between [=] and [&], which I figured out basically when I hit Save and then Xeo and ForEver found basically the same issue.

Comment: @James: I added the error message when writing it with decltype(x_.begin()). I suspect it's the .begin() part, but I'm not qualified to tell if it should be all right according to the standard (probably not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class some_class
{
   public:
        some_class()
        {
            x_["0"] = "0";
            x_["1"] = "1";

            y_[0] = x_.find("0");
            y_[1] = x_.find("1");
        }

        int some_function()
        {
            if(std::find(y_.begin(), y_.end(), x_.find("1")) != y_.end())
            {
                std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;

                return 1001;
            }

            return -1001;
        }

   private:
       std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> x_;
       std::array<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator, 2> y_;
};

void function(some_class cl)
{
    cl.some_function();
}

int main()
{
    some_class c;
    function(c);
}
```

Your `iterators` points on elements of another `map`, that stored in `this` after `copy-ctor`, and in `find` there is comparison.

```
    bool operator==(const _Myiter& _Right) const
        {   // test for iterator equality
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (this->_Getcont() == 0
            || this->_Getcont() != _Right._Getcont())
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("list iterators incompatible");
            _SCL_SECURE_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
            }
```

for decltype -

```
std::unordered_map<string, string> x_;
std::array<decltype(x_.begin()), 2> y_;
```

incorrect in `class-block`, since there is no object. This will works if `x_` will be `static`.

Comment: Yep, this was basically it. Too long time awake, but "bug talk" seem to always help. Let's now just hope this will be useful to someone else too. :)